# Create dynamic audio broadcast stream (node, ffmpeg, ..?)

Tags: node.js, audio, ffmpeg, stream, rtsp

I have coded a videoboard. Like a soundboard but with video. You go to one URL that's just a black screen and another one which has a list of different videos (sender). When you click one of these videos it plays on the black screen (receiver). If you play 2 different videos at the same time both videos are shown next to each other on the receiver. That's working fine for several months now. It just creates multiple html video-elements with multiple source-tags (x265 mp4 and vp9 webm).

I recently made a discord bot which takes the webm, extracts the opus stream and plays its sound in the voice channel where the bot is connected. This has one disadvantage: It can only play one sound at a time. It happens a lot that there are multiple videos/sounds playing at the same time so this a bit of a bummer.

So I thought I should create a audiostream on the server which hosts the videoboard and just connect the bot to that stream. But I have no clue how to do this. All I know is that it's very likely going to involve ffmpeg.

What would be the best option here? What I think I would need is basically an infinite silence stream and the possibility to add a audio file onto that stream at any point which will play simultaneously with other audio files that were added before and have not ended payback yet. How is that possible? Somehow with m3u8 playlist-files or via rtsp protocol?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I think it can be helpful for you https://bitbucket.org/kaleniuk_ihor/neuro_vision/src/db_watch/
Also this library was very useful for me https://github.com/kyriesent/node-rtsp-stream you can just install `npm i node-rtsp-stream`